# Adding variables to a SQL Server stored procedure that takes XML as a param

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

Can I use variables when passing XML to a stored procedure? I'm trying to avoid having to do manual queries and then pasting it into the XML to execute the stored procedure.

For example below is possible to pass `NEWID()` or even a `SELECT` statement in for one of the XML records - namely the ID?

```
exec spChangeRecordXML '<SP_ChangeRecordXML><Details><TableName>table1</TableName><ModificationType>Insert</ModificationType><Field><Name>ID</Name><Value>9b99e3ce-a675-44b9-9c6e-cedc1a1c2834</Value></Field><Field><Name>strtName</Name><Value>TEST2</Value></Field><Field><Name>strName</Name><Value>TEST2</Value></Field><Field><Name>DeptID</Name><Value>5894f6cc-7236-482a-af0f-08d0d15e6d5c</Value></Field></SP_ChangeRecordXML>'
```

Comment: A different way is to use User Table Value types as input, when one needs a lot of individual values passed in.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter for an SP can be any data type you like, including custom data types (which is how you can pass Table Parameters). Having an SP with an xml parameter is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: But can I dynamically generate part of that XML for example a new GUID and if so how would that get passed?

Comment: @user3543017 Who will be the caller (=the XML's sender)? An external application or other code within your database?

Comment: The call will be manually made by myself.  The SP is already written and I'm basically trying to bypass the GUI that sits in front of this.  And while I can do so simply by executing the SP and manually generating a few of the necessary identifiers I'm trying to that dynamically to avoid having to run a few select statements before I call the SP.

Answer (score 0):

It looks, as if you wanted to have a generic SP for any kind of data manipulation. You send in *Hey, insert the following fields into my table "table1"!* and the SP forms the appropriate statement and execute this against the database. Correct?

About your question:

It is perfectly okay to have an SP with an XML parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestWithXML(@SomeXML XML)
AS
BEGIN
    --Do something with the XML
    SELECT fld.value(N'(Name/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
          ,fld.value(N'(Value/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
    FROM @SomeXml.nodes(N'//Field') AS A(fld)
END
GO
```

--now I call this SP in various ways:

```
--fill a variable with a given XML
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<SP_ChangeRecordXML>
  <Details>
    <TableName>table1</TableName>
    <ModificationType>Insert</ModificationType>
    <Field>
      <Name>ID</Name>
      <Value>9b99e3ce-a675-44b9-9c6e-cedc1a1c2834</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name>strtName</Name>
      <Value>TEST2</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name>strName</Name>
      <Value>TEST2</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name>DeptID</Name>
      <Value>5894f6cc-7236-482a-af0f-08d0d15e6d5c</Value>
    </Field>
  </Details>
</SP_ChangeRecordXML>'

--call the SP with an XML variable
EXEC dbo.TestWithXML @SomeXML=@xml;

--call the SP with an XML on string base
EXEC dbo.TestWithXML @SomeXML='<root><Field><Name>SomeName</Name><Value>SomeValue</Value></Field></root>';

--Set the variable from above to an XML "on the fly"
SET @xml=(SELECT 'testName' AS [Name], 'testValue' AS [Value] FOR XML PATH('Field'),ROOT('root'),TYPE);
--and call the SP with this
EXEC dbo.TestWithXML @SomeXML=@xml;

--Clean up
GO
DROP PROCEDURE dbo.TestWithXML;
```

More important to me seems the question about the code **within** this SP.

Generic approaches are fine but tend to grow ugly when deployed...

An XML as parameter is great, as you can pass over literally any kind and amount of data. But the SP is lost, if you do not know what's inside. This XML must not change in structure (otherwise you'd need versioning - even worse!)

Reading from the XML might additionally need some meta data, especially the data type. Well, one could rely on implicit conversions, read everything as string and pass it into the `INSERT` within quotes. This will work in most cases (make sure you use datetime in ISO8601 and it will not work with base64 encoded binaries...). I'd read the `DATA_TYPE` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.column` probably.

It might be a good idea to generate CRUD procedures for all your tables and call them internally, using the XML's work load as parameters. This would allow you to implement businessrules without bloating your generic SP.

### UPDATE Modify the XML

From your comment I get the idea, that you might need something else:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<SP_ChangeRecordXML>
  <Details>
    <TableName>table1</TableName>
    <ModificationType>Insert</ModificationType>
    <Field>
      <Name>ID</Name>
      <Value>9b99e3ce-a675-44b9-9c6e-cedc1a1c2834</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name>strtName</Name>
      <Value>TEST2</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name>strName</Name>
      <Value>TEST2</Value>
    </Field>
    <Field>
      <Name>DeptID</Name>
      <Value>5894f6cc-7236-482a-af0f-08d0d15e6d5c</Value>
    </Field>
  </Details>
</SP_ChangeRecordXML>';
```

--Declare a variable holding then new value

```
DECLARE @ReplaceID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER=NEWID();
SELECT @ReplaceID;
```

--Use this variable within `XQuery/XPath` with `sql:variable()`

```
SET @xml.modify(N'replace value of (//Field[Name="ID"]/Value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@ReplaceID")');
SELECT @xml;
```

Comment: I'd be trying to so something like this: declare a varaiable for NEWID() and pass that into the xml for the field "ID".

Comment: @user3543017 It think you are looking for `.modify()`. See my update.